# "Stay on it" meaning in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

In one of American Dad's episodes (cartoon), there's a closing scene where Dad commands to his CIA colleagues to follow his daughter (who used to be a strip dancer) and then responds to one of them:

> Yes, I know she's got a great ass. Stay on it.

*Stay on* means to remain doing something, but I think natives will understand it better whether Dad is asking his operatives to remain following her or just threatens them to stop talking about his daughter's body's nice parts (hm, there should be a special word for 'nice parts of a human body', any ideas?)
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: More context please?

Comment: Maybe the link will help? Don't really know how to give more context. The last scene, here (21:10) http://www.kisspanda.net/american-dad-season-1-episode-3-stan-knows-best/

Comment: What can it mean, in general? "Stay on it". Keep going on. Keep doing what you are doing. Do what you are doing. Do your business. What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In US colloquial English *ass* is often used [synecdochally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) to designate a person emphatically, especially a person considered as a physical being.

> "I'm gonna whup his ass" *doesn't mean that I am literally going to beat his buttocks; it means I have a strong intention of beating him*.

To "be **on**" somebody has two broad meanings: either to apply pressure to him or to stay close to him, keep him under close observation. Consequently,

> "Get on his ass" doesn't mean literally position yourself on his buttocks; it means continue to be very much "on" him.

In this case, the speaker makes a pun on *ass*: he acknowledges that in the ordinary sense she has attractive buttocks, and then twists the word into its synecdochic sense, instructing his subordinates to "stay on [her ass]", continue to keep her under close observation and not lose track of her whereabouts.

Comment: great explanation. I was thinking pretty much the same way but still had a bit of a doubt about the usage of the idiom "stay on". Though, as you have mentioned, the "it" is for "ass" and when you put things that way everything gets in its place. Thank you there!